# Adding a $var intro a $var

Tags: php, html, css, variables

I am newbie in php, but I need to modify some string in order to add a link with rel intro a visual composer shortcode, an animated icon.
The problem is that I have this variable, by default where i should add two variables only if insered.

Here is the originary code:

```
$svg_icon = '<div class="svg-icon-holder" data-size="'. $icon_size . '" data-animation-speed="'.$animation_speed_time.'" data-animation="'.$enable_animation.'" data-animation-delay="'.$animation_delay.'" data-color="'.strtolower($color) .'"><span>'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts/svg/' . $image .'</span></div>';
```

The problem is that: I should insert a `<a href="'. $icon_link . '" rel="'. $icon_link_rel .'">` before the tag `<div>` into the code and a `</a>` after the closing div BUT this only if variable `&icon_link` is set, if not, the `<a>` tag should not appear as I do not need to have a link to all icons.

Hope I have explained myself well, if not let me know!

Regards, Alin.

Comment: Why not make an `if` statement and check for that condition, then rearrange the html-tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do an `if-statement`, if `$icon_link` is defined and set, then add your `<a>` tag to your `$svg_icon` variable using a dot(`.`):

```
 $svg_icon = '<div class="svg-icon-holder" data-size="'. $icon_size . '" data-animation-speed="'.$animation_speed_time.'" data-animation="'.$enable_animation.'" data-animation-delay="'.$animation_delay.'" data-color="'.strtolower($color) .'"><span>'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts/svg/' . $image .'</span></div>';
 if($icon_link)
  {
      $svg_icon = '<a href="'. $icon_link . '" rel="'. $icon_link_rel .'">'.
                  $svg_icon.'</a>';
  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you downvote? that could help me improve my answer

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer, this worked for me and looks like the easiest way!  Could someone else tell me if this code is great?

Comment: @AlinIonescu I'm glad i could help. if this answer has solved your question please mark it as accepted by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself

Answer (score 1):

Just use a if statment. You are manipulating string, so you can easily add words to an other string like that

```
if ($icon_link){
    $beginning = "<a href='$icon_link' rel='$icon_link_rel'>";
    $ending = "</a>"
}
else {
    $beginning = "";
    $ending = ""
}
$svg_icon = "$beginning<div class='svg-icon-holder' data-size='$icon_size' data-animation-speed='$animation_speed_time' data-animation='$enable_animation' data-animation-delay='$animation_delay' data-color='".strtolower($color)."'>
<span>".get_template_directory_uri()."/css/fonts/svg/$image</span></div>$ending";
```

Comment: Where is the closing `</a>`

Comment: now it just starts to look like a mess. I think LuthandoLoot came up with a better answer.

Comment: We posted it at the same time, his is better I have never said the opposite!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to format string using [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) instead of pasting the string together using dots. You could put the `$svg_icon` string together using `sprintf` with only the `<div>` tag. After that just wrap an `<a>` tag around `$svg_icon` if `$icon_link` is defined:

```
$svg_icon_format = '<div class="svg-icon-holder" data-size="%d" data-animation-speed="%d" data-animation="%d" data-animation-delay="%d" data-color="%d"><span>%s</span></div>';

$values = array(..enter values here..);

$svg_icon = sprintf($svg_icon_format,$values);

if(isset($icon_link) && isset($icon_link_rel)) {
    $svg_icon = sprintf('<a href="%s" rel="%s">%s</a>',$icon_link,$svg_icon,$icon_link_rel);
}
```

**Disclaimer**: This code is not tested. Please look at the sprintf documentation I linked and try writing the code yourself.

Answer (score -1):

First, do not write everything on one line, so it fits on the screen here on SO (and maybe in your code too).

Second, I would use instring variables. In php you can use singlequotes, where your string gets used as-is, or you can use doublequotes, where you can use variables in it. like `echo "Hey, my name is $name";` $name here would get exchanged by the value of the variable. If you need doublequotes in the string, you can escape them with a backslash like  `\"`

Third, you can use inline if-else, folowing syntax: `$str = boolean ? "str if true" : "str if false"`

```
$svg_icon = isset($icon_link) ? "<a href=\"$icon_link\"
    rel=\"$icon_link_rel\">" : '' . //add your opening <a> if needed
    "<div class=\"svg-icon-holder\" 
    data-size=\"$icon_size\" data-animation-speed=\"$animation_speed_time\"
    data-animation=\"$enable_animation\" 
    data-animation-delay=\"$animation_delay\"
    data-color=\"strtolower($color) \"><span>" 
    . get_template_directory_uri()
    . "/css/fonts/svg/ $image </span></div>"
    . isset($icon_link) ? '<\a>' : ''; //add your closing <\a> if needed
```

Comment: You tell him not to write everthing on one line, but you give him an answer where you put everthing in one line by using an inline if statement....